# Adding ACL support to parse4cn1

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

I'm working on an app written in Codename One together with the parse4cn1 library, the combination of which is a real pleasure to use. However, I need support for a few things in parse4cn1 that are not implemented, most importantly ACL and was wondering if Chidiebere has any hints on how to do this (e.g. how did you implement parse4cn1 yourself - from scratch or copying the open source Parse SDK for Android)? If I manage to do something of a decent quality I will try to share back. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never got around implementing ACLs (it's still on the TODO list). `parse4cn1`'s interface closes resembles the Parse Android SDK interface and I'll like it to stay that way for convenience. In this case, the interface of interest would be the ParseACL which is documented [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/).

The actual implementation will need to be done via [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#security) calls.

Things to bear in mind:

1. We use the Android SDK API simply for defining methods and signatures for the corresponding class in ParseACL but do *not* use the SDKs for anything can be be done via REST.
2. By design, any calls requiring the master key will not be supported in `parse4cn1` due to security considerations. If really needed, the functionality should be exposed via server-side cloud code.
3. Pull requests without unit tests for the added functionality or breaking existing tests will be rejected.
4. See also the [Contributions](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1#contributing) section of the `parse4cn1` github repo.

Good luck with your implementation and I hope to see a PR from you soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

It was implemented from a Java port on top of the REST API's [here](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/) but was later modified to use the SDK's to allow things like push (which are now no longer relevant).

In the past I just contributed pull a request to the project to get the fixes/features I needed. It was really easy to work with and compile.

Comment: Your remark that push is no longer relevant is not correct. The Parse Open Source Server _does_ support push (currently for iOS and Android); see this [announcement](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-server-push-notifications/). I'm yet to investigate in detail but in principle, push will still be configurable via Parse. At the moment, other push services like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) look like an easier way to go.

Comment: I thought I saw that it was not a part of the open source releases. Either way as you mention the provisioning complexity of push makes it impractical here.